# Create empty data.frame with column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a empty data frame with two columns and unknown number of row. I would like to specify the names of the columns. I ran the following command

```
dat <- data.frame("id"=numeric(),"nobs"=numeric())
```

I can test the result by running

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id  : num 
 $ nobs: num
```

But later on when I insert data into this data frame using rbind in the following command, the names of the columns are also changed

```
  for (i in id) {
    nobs = nrow(na.omit(read.csv(files_list[i])))
    dat = rbind(dat, c(i,nobs))
  }
```

After for loop this is the value of dat

```
dat
  X3 X243
1  3  243
```

And str command shows the following

```
str(dat)

'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X3  : num 3
 $ X243: num 243
```

Can any one tell why are the col names in data frame change

**EDIT:**

My lazy solution to fix the problem is to run the follwing commands after for loop that binds data to my data.frame

```
names(dat)[1] = "id"
names(dat)[2] = "nobs"
```

Comment: simpler example: `rbind(dat,c(3,243))`

Comment: I was surprised that rbinding atomic vector `c(i,nobs)` to dataframe did not throw an error. Would have imagined a need for `list(id=i,nobs=nobs)`

Comment: somebody was doing the coursera course... I was having trouble with this myself, and also had constructed the lazy solution!  Have you discovered the solution since then?

Answer (score 10):

Interestingly, the `rbind.data.frame` function throws away all values passed that have zero rows. It basically happens in this line

```
allargs <- allargs[nr > 0L]
```

so passing in a data.frame with no rows, is really like not passing it in nothing at all. Another good example why it's almost always a bad idea to try to build a data.frame row-by-row. Better to build vectors and then combine into a data.frame only when done.

Comment: From the comments in the source: "drop any zero-row data frames, as they may not have proper column types (e.g. NULL)". It's been that way since at least 2007. Perhaps it's not the most intuitive default behavior, but I do generally think it's a good idea to discourage people from using data.frames in this way (ie building them row-by-row).

Comment: @MrFlick So how do I overcome this problem, in my case I don't know the number of rows for data.frame as I read the data from another data.frame using for loop.

Comment: @KhurramMajeed. Well, don't use a loop comes to mind. The best strategy is usually to build a column at a time. I don't know what you're really doing, but there may very well be a more R-like™ way to do it.

Comment: A lazy solution is to rename the columns names after the loop by using `names(dat)[1] = "id"`  and `names(dat)[2] = "obs"`

Comment: use your for loop to read the data into a *list* of data frames, then `do.call(rbind,list_of_frames)`

Answer (score 2):

```
dat = data.frame(col1=numeric(), col2=numeric())  

...loop
    dat[, dim(dat)[1] + 1] = c(324, 234)
```

This keeps the column names

Answer (score 1):

You should try specify your column names inside the rbind():

`dat = rbind(dat, data.frame("id" = i, "nobs" = nobs))`

Answer (score 0):

I would change how you're appending the data to the data frame. Since rbind seems to remove the column names, just replace the indexed location.

```
dat <- data.frame("id"=numeric(),"nobs"=numeric())  

for (i in id) {
   dat[i,] <- nrow(na.omit(read.csv(files_list[i])))

 }
```

FYI, Default data frame creation converts all strings to factors, not an issue here, since all your data formats are numeric. But if you had a character(), you might want to turn off the default stringsAsFactors=FALSE, to append character lists.